# How do I simulate an RF mixer in PSS or harmomic balance with an autonomous local oscillator?

Tags: simulation, cadence, non-linear

I am designing a CMOS RF downconversion signal chain comprised of a local oscillator and mixer (the LNA is not yet included) using the Cadence Virtuoso Circuit Design Suite with ADE XL as my simulator.

The oscillator is based on a resonant element which should ideally oscillate at 2.400 GHz, but my design tunes it to *approximately* 2.383 GHz (for a sample set of values that I'm working with throughout this iteration of the design), +/- phase noise on each cycle. I would like to simulate with the LO included in the chain, so I can consider effects such as injection locking/pulling, loading effects, and phase noise.

[image]

[image]

In order to prepare to simulate active mixer designs and establish a performance baseline, I'm trying to get the whole chain working with a simple double-balanced passive mixer. My testbench drives the RF input of the mixer using a 2.385 GHz input, for an intended downconverted frequency of approximately 2 MHz.

I can run a transient simulation, wherein the oscillator starts up, and the mixer successfully downconverts to approximately 2 MHz (but not exactly, since the oscillator is not tuned exactly to 2.383 GHz). The waveform is decently clean, but (obviously) has significant harmonics and experiences the phase noise of the oscillator. Because the testbench works in transient analysis, I can likely eliminate the most obvious factors of the circuit simply not working.

However, I have severe trouble getting a harmonic balance or periodic-steady-state simulation to succeed with sensible results.

When I use the `shooting` engine, PSS fails to converge with messages such as the following:

> ```
> Conv norm = 44.7e+03, max dV(I28.net8) = 11.032 V, took 14.92 s.
> ```

on each PSS iteration, or creates such long beat periods that the simulation cannot complete in a reasonable time. Even when I tried measuring my LO frequency as precisely as possible, and setting the RF input to that frequency * 1.001, pss cannot converge. My PSS settings are as follows:

[image]

Meanwhile, in harmonic-balance, the simulation runs for a time of tstab (set to allow the oscillator to start up), yet the actual harmonic-balance outputs are in the picovolts, meaning that hb is somehow using the near-steady-state before the oscillator starts up, when the following settings are given:

[image]

QPSS simply won't run because the oscillator is not an independent source:

> ```
> Warning from spectre during Quasi-Periodic Steady State Analysis `qpss'.
>     WARNING (SPCRTRF-15267): The number of sources 1 is less than the number of funds 2 set in analysis.Please make sure the analysis is set up correctly.
> Error found by spectre during Quasi-Periodic Steady State Analysis `qpss'.
>     ERROR (SPCRTRF-15082): The fundamental name lo specified by the 'funds' parameter is either not associated with any fundamental name specified in the input sources, or is not unique.
> ```

Am I making a complete misunderstanding of the fundamentals here, or is there some small option that I overlooked?

Comment: Maybe you need to add two sources, on top of each other, each representing one frequency? E.g. similarly to what a two-tone analysis in audio might be done, only the program maybe actually expects two separate sources to represent the two tones (as opposed to a behavioural source with `sin(a)+sin(b)`, for example). I never touched Cadence, so these are just guesses.

Comment: @concernedcitizen that's the crux of the issue. I don't want to analyze two behavioral sources (or a single source with a sum, which I don't have). I've already done that and have early figures for my system performance that I want to refine. I'm looking to see how my circuit performs with my actual oscillator, made of noisy, nonideal transistors and all the problems and effects that come with them.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but I can't help. Maybe the official help has something about that particular analysis?

Comment: I'll look at docs again but the set that I have access to (because of paywall/support account access) didn't adequately discuss the application, just giving a reference of each parameter.