# How to measure noise in cadence with this RF circuit?

Tags: rf, noise, cadence

This is the circuit where i want to measure the noise.

[image]

I'm new in cadence so i dont know how to do it. I tried making putting some things here but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of noise are you looking to measure? Oscillator phase noise? Mixer noise figure? Overall NF? If you're talking about overall noise, then you may hit the same roadblock as my [old unanswered question from over a year ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563076/how-do-i-simulate-an-rf-mixer-in-pss-or-harmomic-balance-with-an-autonomous-loca). I've even tried bountying it, but was unable to get an answer; in that case, separate phase noise for the oscillator and NF for the mixer may be your best bet.

Comment: I want the overall noise, i might try your approach if things dont work out

Comment: Then you'd either transient noise or a multirate noise simulation. As you've shown it, PSS relative to PORT0 isn't likely to work, because PORT0 isn't driving the main periodic behavior - it's *beats* between PORT0 and the LO. Your options are either to do transient noise (which is not time efficient or very insightful), or somehow get a multirate analysis like hb/pss/qpss working over the beat of LO's autonomous oscillation and PORT0. I don't have a working approach in the linked question - I gave up without an answer and just taped out + measured a physical circuit instead.